# Nested Grid en asp.Net con c# utilizando webForms

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, webforms

Hola comunidad alguien tendrá un articulo de como implementar el Grid anidado de JQuery(jqxGrid) ya que lo he intentado pero aun no me sale. De antemano gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Pero en si que quieres hacer solo mostrar registros o agregar checkbox, editar ?
aqui un ejemplo simple

```js
$(document).ready(function ()
{
        // prepare the data
            var data = new Array();
            var firstNames =
            [
                "Andrew", "Nancy", "Shelley", "Regina", "Yoshi", "Antoni", "Mayumi", "Ian", "Peter", "Lars", "Petra", "Martin", "Sven", "Elio", "Beate", "Cheryl", "Michael", "Guylene"
            ];
            var lastNames =
            [
                "Fuller", "Davolio", "Burke", "Murphy", "Nagase", "Saavedra", "Ohno", "Devling", "Wilson", "Peterson", "Winkler", "Bein", "Petersen", "Rossi", "Vileid", "Saylor", "Bjorn", "Nodier"
            ];
            var productNames =
            [
                "Black Tea", "Green Tea", "Caffe Espresso", "Doubleshot Espresso", "Caffe Latte", "White Chocolate Mocha", "Cramel Latte", "Caffe Americano", "Cappuccino", "Espresso Truffle", "Espresso con Panna", "Peppermint Mocha Twist"
            ];
            var priceValues =
            [
                "2.25", "1.5", "3.0", "3.3", "4.5", "3.6", "3.8", "2.5", "5.0", "1.75", "3.25", "4.0"
            ];
            for (var i = 0; i < 200; i++) {
                var row = {};
                var productindex = Math.floor(Math.random() * productNames.length);
                var price = parseFloat(priceValues[productindex]);
                var quantity = 1 + Math.round(Math.random() * 10);
                row["firstname"] = firstNames[Math.floor(Math.random() * firstNames.length)];
                row["lastname"] = lastNames[Math.floor(Math.random() * lastNames.length)];
                row["productname"] = productNames[productindex];
                row["price"] = price;
                row["quantity"] = quantity;
                row["total"] = price * quantity;
                data[i] = row;
            }
            var source =
            {
                localdata: data,
                datatype: "array",
                datafields:
                [
                    { name: 'firstname', type: 'string' },
                    { name: 'lastname', type: 'string' },
                    { name: 'productname', type: 'string' },
                    { name: 'quantity', type: 'number' },
                    { name: 'price', type: 'number' },
                    { name: 'total', type: 'number' }
                ]
            };
            var dataAdapter = new $.jqx.dataAdapter(source);
       
            $("#jqxgrid").jqxGrid(
            {
                width: 850,
                source: dataAdapter,
                columnsresize: true,
                columns: [
                  { text: 'Name', datafield: 'firstname', width: 120 },
                  { text: 'Last Name', datafield: 'lastname', width: 120 },
                  { text: 'Product', datafield: 'productname', width: 180 },
                  { text: 'Quantity', datafield: 'quantity', width: 80, cellsalign: 'right' },
                  { text: 'Unit Price', datafield: 'price', width: 90, cellsalign: 'right', cellsformat: 'c2' },
                  { text: 'Total', datafield: 'total', cellsalign: 'right', cellsformat: 'c2' }
                ]
            });
});
```

```html
<HTML>
 <HEAD>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.jqwidgets.com/public/jqwidgets/styles/jqx.base.css">
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.jqwidgets.com/public/jqwidgets/styles/jqx.arctic.css">
  
   <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.jqwidgets.com/public/jqwidgets/jqx-all.js"></script>
 </HEAD>
 <BODY>
    <div id="jqxgrid"></div>
 </BODY>
</HTML>
```

saludos

Comment: hola @Miguel Zarate lo que quiero es saber como implementar un grid anidado, mis datos los obtengo de manera correcta el problema es que no se como implementar el grid anidado espero puedas ayudarme. Gracias.

Comment: Te agregue otro ejemplo pero ahora con grid anidado.

Comment: Hola @Miguel Zarate he implemado este grid pero se queda cargando puedes verificar mi pregunta como 
jqxGrid [https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/241599/jqxgrid-anidado-se-queda-cargando-en-asp-net] aqui coloco codigo y explico mejor. Gracias por tu ayuda.

Comment: Hola @Miguel Zarate si gustas ver mi codigo completo puedes verlo aqui [https://www.jqwidgets.com/community/topic/nested-grid-in-asp-net-c-with-webforms/]

Comment: de entrada en la llamada para carga de datos es errornea no tienes un objetojson  bien formado en data , de tu llamada ajax deberia ser  var parametros='{"id_intervalo":"' + id_Intervalo + '","Sucursal":"' + Sucursal + '","ROl":"' + id_Rol + '"}';
        console.log(parametros);

Comment: Hola @Miguel Zarate es correcto he corregido ese error el problema en si es que me sigue mostrando ciclado el segundo grid.

Comment: crees que puedas subir tu codigo a https://jsfiddle.net/ porque de la liga que enviaste no se encuentra todo completo.

Answer (score 0):

ok, es una respuesta larga como para explicar todo el procedimiento ,
al final agrego la referencia, modifique los datos de entrada que se entienda
mejor.

```js
        $(document).ready(function () {
        
        ////
        var employees=[
   {
      "EmployeeID": "5",
      "LastName": "Buchanan",
      "FirstName": "Steven",
      "Title": "Sales Manager",
      "TitleOfCourtesy": "Mr.",
      "BirthDate": "1955-03-04",
      "HireDate": "1993-10-17",
      "Address": "14 Garrett Hill",
      "City": "London",
      "Region": [],
      "PostalCode": "SW1 8JR",
      "Extension": "3453",
     
      "ReportsTo": "2",
     },
   {
      "EmployeeID": "8",
      "LastName": "Callahan",
      "FirstName": "Laura",
      "Title": "Inside Sales Coordinator",
      "TitleOfCourtesy": "Ms.",
      "BirthDate": "1958-01-09",
      "HireDate": "1994-03-05",
      "Address": "4726 - 11th Ave. N.E.",
      "City": "Seattle",
      "Region": "WA",
      "PostalCode": "98105",
      "Extension": "2344",
        "ReportsTo": "2",
   
   }
]

 var source =
            {
                dataType: "json",
                dataFields: [
                    { name: 'EmployeeID', type: 'number' },
                    { name: 'LastName', type: 'string' },
                    { name: 'FirstName', type: 'string' },
                    { name: 'Country', type: 'string' },
                    { name: 'City', type: 'string' },
                    { name: 'Address', type: 'string' },
                    { name: 'Title', type: 'string' },
                    { name: 'HireDate', type: 'date' },
                    { name: 'children', type: 'array' },
                    { name: 'expanded', type: 'bool' },
                    { name: 'BirthDate', type: 'date' },
                    
                ],
                hierarchy:
                {
                    root: 'children'
                },
                id: 'EmployeeID',
                localData: employees
            };

        
       
          
            var employeesAdapter = new $.jqx.dataAdapter(source);
       
       ///
            ///order details
           var orderDetails=[ {
      "OrderID": "10248",
      "CustomerID": "VINET",
      "EmployeeID": "5",
      "OrderDate": "1996-07-04T14:25:55",
      "RequiredDate": "1996-08-01T06:43:44",
      "ShippedDate": "1996-07-16T04:00:12",
      "ShipVia": "3",
      "Freight": "32.3800",
      "ShipName": "Vins et alcools Chevalier",
      "ShipAddress": "59 rue de l'Abbaye",
      "ShipCity": "Reims",
      "ShipRegion": [],
      "ShipPostalCode": "51100",
      "ShipCountry": "France"   
   },
   {
      "OrderID": "10248",
      "CustomerID": "Pharma",
      "EmployeeID": "8",
      "OrderDate": "1999-07-04T14:25:55",
      "RequiredDate": "1999-06-01T06:43:44",
      "ShippedDate": "1999-05-16T04:00:12",
      "ShipVia": "3",
      "Freight": "32.3800",
      "ShipName": "flu shots extra",
      "ShipAddress": "1th avenue  ",
      "ShipCity": "Floral Park",
       "ShipPostalCode": "111001",
      "ShipCountry": "USA"   
   }
]
            
            ///
            
      
            var ordersSource =
            {
                datatype: "json",
                datafields: [
                    { name: 'EmployeeID', type: 'string' },
                    { name: 'ShipName', type: 'string' },
                    { name: 'ShipAddress', type: 'string' },
                    { name: 'ShipCity', type: 'string' },
                    { name: 'ShipCountry', type: 'string' },
                    { name: 'ShippedDate', type: 'date' }
                ],
                hierarchy:
                {
                    root: 'children'
                },
                id: 'EmployeeID',
                localData: orderDetails
            };
            var ordersDataAdapter = new $.jqx.dataAdapter(ordersSource, { autoBind: true });
            orders = ordersDataAdapter.records;
            var nestedGrids = new Array();
            // create nested grid.
            var initrowdetails = function (index, parentElement, gridElement, record) {
                var id = record.uid.toString();
                var grid = $($(parentElement).children()[0]);
                nestedGrids[index] = grid;
                var filtergroup = new $.jqx.filter();
                var filter_or_operator = 1;
                var filtervalue = id;
                var filtercondition = 'equal';
                var filter = filtergroup.createfilter('stringfilter', filtervalue, filtercondition);
                // fill the orders depending on the id.
                var ordersbyid = [];
                for (var m = 0; m < orders.length; m++) {
                    var result = filter.evaluate(orders[m]["EmployeeID"]);
                    if (result)
                        ordersbyid.push(orders[m]);
                }
                var orderssource = { datafields: [
                    { name: 'EmployeeID', type: 'string' },
                    { name: 'ShipName', type: 'string' },
                    { name: 'ShipAddress', type: 'string' },
                    { name: 'ShipCity', type: 'string' },
                    { name: 'ShipCountry', type: 'string' },
                    { name: 'ShippedDate', type: 'date' }
                ],
                    id: 'OrderID',
                    localdata: ordersbyid
                }
                var nestedGridAdapter = new $.jqx.dataAdapter(orderssource);
                if (grid != null) {
                    grid.jqxGrid({
                        source: nestedGridAdapter, width: 780, height: 200,
                        columns: [
                          { text: 'Ship Name', datafield: 'ShipName', width: 200 },
                          { text: 'Ship Address', datafield: 'ShipAddress', width: 200 },
                          { text: 'Ship City', datafield: 'ShipCity', width: 150 },
                          { text: 'Ship Country', datafield: 'ShipCountry', width: 150 },
                          { text: 'Shipped Date', datafield: 'ShippedDate', width: 200 }
                       ]
                    });
                }
            }
            var photorenderer = function (row, column, value) {
                var name = $('#grid').jqxGrid('getrowdata', row).FirstName;
                var imgurl = 'https://www.jqwidgets.com/jquery-widgets-demo/images/' + name.toLowerCase() + '.png';
                var img = '<div style="background: white;"><img style="margin:2px; margin-left: 10px;" width="32" height="32" src="' + imgurl + '"></div>';
                return img;
            }
            var renderer = function (row, column, value) {
                return '<span style="margin-left: 4px; margin-top: 9px; float: left;">' + value + '</span>';
            }
            // creage grid
            $("#grid").jqxGrid(
            {
                width: getWidth('Grid'),
                height: 365,
                source: source,
                rowdetails: true,
                rowsheight: 35,
                initrowdetails: initrowdetails,
                rowdetailstemplate: { rowdetails: "<div id='grid' style='margin: 10px;'></div>", rowdetailsheight: 220, rowdetailshidden: true },
                ready: function () {
                    $("#grid").jqxGrid('showrowdetails', 1);
                },
                columns: [
                      { text: 'Photo', width: 50, cellsrenderer: photorenderer },
                      { text: 'First Name', datafield: 'FirstName', width: 100, cellsrenderer: renderer },
                      { text: 'Last Name', datafield: 'LastName', width: 100, cellsrenderer: renderer },
                      { text: 'Title', datafield: 'Title', width: 180, cellsrenderer: renderer },
                      { text: 'Address', datafield: 'Address', width: 300, cellsrenderer: renderer },
                      { text: 'City', datafield: 'City', width: 170, cellsrenderer: renderer }
                  ]
            });
        });
```

```html
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.jqwidgets.com/jquery-widgets-demo/jqwidgets/styles/jqx.base.css" type="text/css" />
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1 maximum-scale=1 minimum-scale=1" />
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.jqwidgets.com/jquery-widgets-demo/scripts/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.jqwidgets.com/jquery-widgets-demo/jqwidgets/jqxcore.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.jqwidgets.com/jquery-widgets-demo/jqwidgets/jqxdata.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.jqwidgets.com/jquery-widgets-demo/jqwidgets/jqxbuttons.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.jqwidgets.com/jquery-widgets-demo/jqwidgets/jqxscrollbar.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.jqwidgets.com/jquery-widgets-demo/jqwidgets/jqxmenu.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.jqwidgets.com/jquery-widgets-demo/jqwidgets/jqxgrid.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.jqwidgets.com/jquery-widgets-demo/jqwidgets/jqxgrid.selection.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.jqwidgets.com/jquery-widgets-demo/jqwidgets/jqxgrid.filter.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.jqwidgets.com/jquery-widgets-demo/jqwidgets/jqxgrid.sort.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.jqwidgets.com/jquery-widgets-demo/scripts/demos.js"></script>

</head>

<body class='default'>

  <div id="grid">
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

te agrego la referencaia:
https://www.jqwidgets.com/jquery-widgets-demo/demos/jqxgrid/index.htm#demos/jqxgrid/nestedgrids.htm